# Grouping multiple groups by group by pandas with multiple values in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a file and in one column 'Saracen ID' has multiple values and i want group basis those values like
1. ('07111',07112') should come under one group.
2. (09084) come under second group
3.  Rest if any in future will fall under third group.

I am trying to group multiple grouping through groupby and get_group

```
group_1=df.groupby('Saracen ID').get_group('07111',07112')
group_2=df.groupby('Saracen ID')get_group('09084')
group_1
group_2
```

I am getting the error
'str' object has not attribute 'take'

How to get multiple groups under one grouping in pandas.

Comment: kindly share data with expected output

Answer (score 1):

The way we filter the group is `loc` + `isin`

```
group_1 = df.loc[df['Saracen ID'].isin(['07111', '07112'])]
```

Comment: Can we do it through .get_group with multiple values

Comment: @JatinKapoor nope we can not